# use freemarker variable in javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, freemarker

I have declared a variable in freemarker as

```
<#assign myvariable= "value">
```

I want to access it in my javascript function like as follows

```
function myfunction(){

    alert(myvariable);

}
```

Answer (score 12):

I guess, at first, you should output that variable into your HTML/JavaScript code, something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myvariable = "${myvariable}";
function myfunction(){
    alert(myvariable);
}
</script>
```

Comment: will we need that quotes in "${x}". ?..what about just ${x}.

Comment: @AhmadBeg depends on type of your variable contents. If it is string, you should quote it, if it is integer or float, you can deal without quotes. This is basic JavaScript.

Comment: it didn't work...it just printing ${x} not value of x...tried without quoted even

Comment: @AhmadBeg yes, you should have placed `myvariable` in place of `x`. My mistake. But you should really read the referance manual for freemaker, this is variable basics.

Comment: That should be `"${myvariable?js_string}"`, or else you will have a problem if the variable contains quotation marks, line-breaks, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can assign freemarker variable to HTML input  field and access it in JavaScript using jquery or document
Here how it is

```
<input id=“freemarkervar” type=“text or hidden” value=“${myVariable}”/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var val = $(“#freemarkervar”).val();
alert(val);

// using JavaScript   
var val=document.getElementById("freemarkervar").value;  
alert(val);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use FreeMarker code in JavaScript straight away.  Here's a sample code where FreeMarker supplies the data of a Morris.js chart.  I think you'll get the idea.

```
new Morris.Area({
    element: 'searchTrend',
    resize: true,
    data: [
    <#list searchCount as sc>
    {day: '${sc.date!?string("yyyy-MM-dd")}', count: ${sc.searches}} <#sep>,
    </#list>
    ],
    xkey: 'day',
    ykeys: ['count'],
    labels: ['Count'],
    xLabelFormat: function (x) { return x.getDate(); }
});
```